# Orphaned source `org-edit-src-code` buffers

Tags: org-mode

I regularly use `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer` to edit an org-mode entry in a separate buffer. 
I also have `org-indirect-buffer-display` set to `current-window` so that `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer` automatically kills an old indirect buffer before creating a new one.

The problem is that sometimes I would be editing a source-code block using `org-edit-src-code`, but then forget to press `C-c C-c` to accept the changes. If I then call `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer` on another entry, the old indirect buffer is killed and the source buffer that `org-edit-src-code` created is orphaned. Pressing `C-c C-c` on that buffer returns "Source buffer disappeared. Aborting". Is there a way to make it so that source code buffers are automatically closed when the original buffer is killed?

TLDR, how can I automatically close `Org Src` created by `org-edit-src-code` when the original org buffer is killed?

Comment: You can add an advice to kill-buffer, assuming that is what org uses to kill an old indirect buffer, to check for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Elisp code adds a function `org+-kill-orphaned-edit-buffers` to the special hook `kill-buffer-query-functions` buffer-locally in Org buffers.

That function scans the Org buffer for overlays with `edit-buffer` property and looks whether that buffer is a live `org-src-edit` buffer. If that is the case it tries to kill the source edit buffer.

The true/false-value of the option `org+-query-before-kill-edit-buffer` determines whether you should be asked for confirmation if a modified source buffer is going to be killed.

If some modified source buffer is not killed then the original Org buffer is also not killed.

But, if `org+-query-before-kill-edit-buffer` is nil (the default case) source edit buffers are killed unconditionally. So you only need to confirm killing if the Org buffer itself is modified.

```el
(require 'cl-lib)

(defcustom org+-query-before-kill-edit-buffer nil
  "Query when killing an edited org src buffer."
  :type 'boolean
  :group 'org-src)

(defun org+-kill-orphaned-edit-buffers (&optional b e)
  "Close orphaned source edit buffers in the region from B to E.
B defaults to `point-min' and E defaults to `point-max'.
In interactive calls B and E are the boundaries of the region
if it is active."
  (interactive (when (region-active-p)
                 (list (region-beginning)
                       (region-end))))
  (unless b (setq b (point-min)))
  (unless e (setq e (point-max)))
  (cl-loop with buf
           for ol being the overlays from b to e
           if (and (setq buf (overlay-get ol 'edit-buffer))
                   (org-src-edit-buffer-p buf))
           unless (with-current-buffer buf
                    (when
                        (or (null org+-query-before-kill-edit-buffer)
                            (null (buffer-modified-p))
                            (save-window-excursion
                              (display-buffer (current-buffer))
                              (y-or-n-p (format "Buffer %s modified; kill anyway? " (buffer-name)))))
                      (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
                      (kill-buffer)))
           return nil
           finally return t))

(defun org+-kill-edit-buffers-at-kill-buffer ()
  "Close source edit buffer when the current Org buffer is killed."
  (add-hook 'kill-buffer-query-functions #'org+-kill-orphaned-edit-buffers t t))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org+-kill-edit-buffers-at-kill-buffer)
```

Comment: That's really nice, I am still learning elisp and using `cl-lib` definitely makes things easier! When trying this, I didn't get the confirmation message when `org+-query-before-kill-edit-buffer` was set to `t`. It seems that for some reason (at least in my setup), killing a modified source buffer does not prompt for a confirmation when the buffer is modified (this is the case for all temporary buffers in my case). I am not sure how to modify this behavior, so until I figure it out I changed `(kill-buffer)` to `(org-edit-src-exit)`.

Comment: Ah, there are [some conditions](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/16ec5f5f2ffd9e114262b0a3a717b772ee0350ae/src/buffer.c#L1735-L1736) that must be met in order to query the user. I have to work that in. Note, that `org-edit-src-exit` did also not give the right results for me. I find a query better than silently adopting the changes from the source buffer.

Comment: @Tohiko I have corrected the query. Could you test again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I do get the confirmation message now. At the moment, when trying to kill the org buffer, the window switches to a previous buffer (like `scratch`) and stays there even if I abort the buffer killing. I added a `(switch-to-buffer (buffer-name))` next to the `y-or-n-p` in a `progn` so that I switch to the source buffer when being prompted to close it. I also changed `return nil` to `do (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))  and return nil` so that I am taken back to the buffer I started with when aborting the buffer-kill.

Comment: Thanks again, I really think this functionality should be added to `org-mode`.

Comment: @Tohiko I added displaying the org src edit buffer to be killed.